# Why can't I use `defconst` to define a new rx?

Tags: rx

I want to define a new `rx` to use *within* another `rx` definition, like so:

```lisp
(defconst my-word
    (rx (or word "*")))

(defconst my-regex
    (rx (1+ my-word)))
```

However, this code returns the following error:

```
Eager macro-expansion failure: (error "Unknown rx symbol 'my-word'")
```

The solution, as per [`rx` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Extending-Rx.html), is to define your `rx` with `rx-define`:

```lisp
(rx-define my-word
    (or word "*"))

(defconst my-regex
    (rx (1+ my-word)))
```

I suspect this has something to do with the sequence of how Emacs loads symbols, but I was just curious as to the specifics of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're just two utterly different things.

`(defconst my-word (rx (or word "*")))` stores the evaluated value `"[[:word:]]\\|\\*"` in the value slot of the `my-word` symbol.

`(rx-define my-word (or word "*"))` sets the symbol property `rx-definition` on the symbol `my-word` with the value `((or word "*"))`

(We can surmise that symbols which are meaningful to `rx` therefore have a `rx-definition` property, and are not evaluated by `rx` as variables.)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
(defconst my-word
    (rx (or word "*")))

(defconst my-regex
    (rx (1+ (regexp my-word))))
```

This works since Emacs 27.

Comment: Thanks for that Michael!  I didn’t realise I needed to use the `regexp` symbol.  I’m marking @phils’ answer as the accepted answer as it technically answers my question better, but I appreciate the tip.